# Singleton in my C++ program

Tags: c++, singleton

I wrote 2 classes, `Agent` and `Timing`. The third class will contain the `main()` function and manage it all. The goal is to create n instances of `Agent` and a SINGLE instance of `Timing`. It's important to mention that `Agent` uses `Timing` fields and `Timing` uses `Agent` functions.
How can I turn `Timing` to [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

```
//Agent.h
#ifndef Timing_h
#define Timing_h
#include <string>
#include "Timing.h"

class Agent{
    public:
        Agent(std::string agentName);
        void SetNextAgent(Agent* nextAgent);
        Agent* GetNextAgent();
        void SendMessage();
        void RecieveMessage(double val);
            //    static Timing runTime;
```

What I thought would solve my problem but I got:

> 'Timing' does not name a type

```
        ~Agent();

    private:
        std::string _agentName;
        double _pID;
        double _mID;
        Agent* _nextAgent;
};
#endif


//Timing.h
#ifndef Timing_h
#define Timing_h

class Timing{
    private:
        typedef struct Message{
            Agent* _agent;
            double _id;
        }Message;
        typedef Message* MessageP;

        Message** _messageArr;
        static int _messagesCount;

    public:
        Timing();
        void AddMessage(Agent* agent, double id);
        void LeaderElected(string name);
        void RunTillWinnerElected();
        ~Timing();
};
#endif
```

Is this really the way to create a singleton and if it is what is the problem?
And if not, how can I turn it to a singleton?

Comment: At least make your code readable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most conventional way to create a singleton has following requirements:

1) The constructor should be private and a static interface shall be provided which in turn creates a static object of the singleton class (which is a member of the class itself) and return it. Basically provide a global point of access.

2) You have to decide in advance if you want the users of the class to be able to extend it and design your class to support it if required.

If the above two requirements are met, there are a number of ways a singleton can be designed including the ones which would work with multi threaded applications.

Comment: For a list of gotch's about singelton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289

Answer (score 10):

This bit looks suspicious in Agent.h ...

```
#ifndef Timing_h
#define Timing_h
```

Seems like it's the same define-guard in Timing.h. Therefore Timing will not be included in Agent.

Change it to

```
#ifndef Agent_h
#define Agent_h
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#C.2B.2B) on the singleton pattern has a good example as well as a nice write up of how a singleton is actually constructed.

Comment: Also note than the code exhibited does not deal with Destruction Order issues or multithreading inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Timing` is not a singleton. Multiple objects can be created. Singleton's typically rely on a `static` method and a private ctor and no copy ctor or `op=`. You have two choices:

- Either create a `static` member `Timing` for `Agent`
- Or, create a `Timing&` member for `Agent` and convert `Timing` to a proper singleton

Depending on your design, if the `Timing` object is never changed by the `Agent` objects you may go ahead `const` qualify the member.

Comment: I chose the second way, with wiki help, but how can i use Timing from Agent? i tried to create a Timing field in Agent.h but i couldn't.
how can i use the getInstance() method from Timing?

Comment: You would assign it to the `Timing&` member variable in `Agent`'s ctor. Then you can manipulate (i.e. call public member methods of `Timing`) on that member variable.

Comment: but when i declare a member: Timing timing, in the Agent.h file
i get error: 'Timing' does not name a type

Comment: You need a forward declaration for `Timing` or will have to `#include` the header file that defines `Timing`.

Comment: ok, i forgot that the getInstance() is statis so i have to use:
(Timing::getInstance()).somthing..

Answer (score 1):

A singleton has to have a private constructor, and then a static method to get an instance of the class, which is a private field in the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Since somebody already mentioned the wikipedia page, I'll also mention another implementation of the Singleton pattern done slightly differently.

If you look at the [Ogre::Singleton](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/OgreSingleton_8h_source.html) class you'll see it done in a different way. It allows you to only call the constructor once (or an assertion happens). So in your setup, you call the constructor. Then at the end of the program, you get this instance and delete it.

It allows you to make a singleton instance, but allow it to be instantiated with different parameters. I don't like it nearly as much as the wikipedia implementation though since it requires you to manage the constructor/destructor of the singleton.

Comment: 2 notes: the code forgo lazy initialization (which should solve multithreading issues) but it means you need to explicitly instantiate both `ms_singleton` variable (to 0) and your singleton. Furthermore you may have crash depending on the initialization order / destruction order which varies from build to build (though it should be diagnosed thanks to the null pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Define a static member of Agent that is of type Timing and initialize the member where it is defined.  This is not strictly a Singleton any more but may model the behaviour you want better.